# SQL Select top frequent records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Table
+----+------+-------+
| ID | Name | Group |
+----+------+-------+
| 0  |   a  |   1   | 
| 1  |   a  |   1   | 
| 2  |   a  |   2   |
| 3  |   a  |   1   |
| 4  |   b  |   1   |
| 5  |   b  |   2   |
| 6  |   b  |   1   |
| 7  |   c  |   2   |
| 8  |   c  |   2   |
| 9  |   c  |   1   |
+----+------+-------+
```

I would like to select top 20 distinct names from a specific group ordered by most frequent name in that group. The result for this example for group 1 would return `a b c` (
a - 3 occurrences, b - 2 occurrences and c - 1 occurrence).

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP(20) [Name], Count(*) FROM Table
WHERE [Group] = 1
GROUP BY [Name]
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
```

Comment: are the result names gonna be distinct?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Top(20) 
   name, group, count(*) as occurences
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name, group
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Comment: You probably want a DESC on your ORDER BY. He wants the most frequent, not the least frequent.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    TOP 20
    Name,
    Group,
    COUNT(1) Count,
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    Name,
    Group
ORDER BY
    Count DESC
```

Comment: This would make a good view or inner select. You need a WHERE clause to get what he's asking for though.