# SQL Server: How to get the top 'N' max occurrences from each group

Tags: sql-server

I have a below dataset and I am trying to get **max occurrences of** `CID` per each `OID`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#SS',N'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #SS
GO
SELECT * INTO #SS FROM (
SELECT 1 AS OID,501 AS CID
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS OID,503 AS CID
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS OID,502 AS CID
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS OID,501 AS CID
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS OID,501 AS CID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS OID,502 AS CID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS OID,502 AS CID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS OID,502 AS CID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS OID,501 AS CID
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS OID,503 AS CID
)A
GO
```

In above sample dataset, I need to get 2 `CID` per each `OID` which occurred maximum times. The expected result could be:

```
OID CID
1   501
1   503
2   501
2   502
```

**This cannot be a duplicate to [SQL Select top frequent records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926838/sql-select-top-frequent-records) because I need this sub-queries and SQL-Server would not accept `ORDER BY` in sub-query and eventually I need a ranking function to solve my issue. Ranking function was not used in the link provided.**

Comment: Why do you get 501 and 503 for OID = 1? There is nothing in your data to define order so it is impossible to get those two values. If you returned the top 2 distinct values it would be 501 and 502.

Comment: @SeanLange he's got an extra 1,503 snuck into the last row.

Comment: @TabAlleman This cannot be a duplicate.  I need this in sub-queries and SQL-Server would not accept ORDER BY. Without ORDER BY, the TOP 2 may not retrieve the required rows. Hope you got my scenario.

Comment: SQL Server does accept ORDER BY in a subquery if TOP is used, and in your case you want TOP 2, so yes, the duplicate does solve your problem.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks, I was not knowing this earlier. Anyways, In my scenario, I wanted it TOP 'N' where I can control using variable but in the thread you suggested I guess we need to use Dynamic SQL which everyone suggests to avoid. And I feel ranking function is an ideal choice for my case. Am I right? Please let me know your expert opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily utilizing ROW_NUMBER. Thanks for Tab Alleman for the clarification on your requirements.

```
select *
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by OID order by count(*) desc)
    from #SS
    group by OID
        , CID
) x
where x.RowNum <= 2
order by x.OID
    , x.CID
```

Comment: I scratched my head with many possible ways of ranking function but forgot to use count(*). Anyways, one of the fastest reply. Thank you.